# Is it dangerous to run fast on the treadmill?

Tags: treadmill, safety

I've been getting into running fast (18 km/hr for about 2 minutes last night) on the treadmill, it's a bit of a rush.

I get bored pretty easily so I find it entertaining to push myself, the running part of my workout is just a warm up anyway.

Now I'm aware of the who dynamic of somebody flying off the end of the treadmill.

The question is - how likely is this to happen, and if it does, what's the potential injury?

Comment: I feel like this question is mostly opinion based. Well for the first part at least, that is the chances of you flying off the treadmill. As for the next part, it depends on how hard you come into contact with any hard surface nearby.

Answer (score 5):

You are only likely to fall off of a treadmill if you set it too high for your performance limits, or get distracted while exercising.

People generally run in a fairly straight line, and if you are able to keep up with the treadmill's pace, then you shouldn't have any problem staying on. The videos you see are people that try to go from standing on the rails to running on a fast moving belt, get distracted and step off the side of the belt, or are otherwise trying to do something cute or funny.

Don't do any of those, and you should be ok. If you are getting to the extreme end of your speed range, then I would highly recommend attaching the magnetic autostop clip to your clothes, so that if you do fall, at least the belt immediately slows down and stops.

Answer (score 1):

Falling of the thread mill is not really a big deal unless of course you hit your head, but it could be just another fun video on youtube. The real problems arise if you keep pushing yourself too hard. Please, go see a doctor before doing intense exercises, it's all fun and games until something snaps and you think you are going to die.

http://heartdisease.about.com/lw/Health-Medicine/Conditions-and-diseases/Heart-Attack-and-Intense-Exercise.-1Q6.htm

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3UyimwIXQg

Comment: Alarmist and does nothing to actually answer the question.

Comment: I did answer the question and I'm not being alarmist, you cannot assume that somebody who just started training would have the endurance of an athlete.

Answer (score 0):

You should always see a doctor before starting a routine of high-intense workouts as Alexandre Borela said and get their approval. Furthermore, the workouts should start of slow (low-medium intensity) and build up to high intensity. It is not good to start at a high intensity when you are not very regular to it.

Also, don't try jumping on the treadmill while it's on high speed, you will fall. Instead, gradually increase its speed to the point where you want it to be.

When running at high speed, every mistake can launch you off from the treadmill so you need to be at 100% focus on every step you take and never do more than you know you can do just to push yourself. You are more likely to hurt yourself rather than develop anything.

And also use everything that can support you if you do fall- Mattresses around the treadmill, the magnetic autostop clip which JohnP mentioned and even have someone close by in case of falling. Better safe than sorry.